# ERROR 1794 (HY000): Slave is not configured or failed to initialize properly

Tags: mysql, replication

This is my `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
server_id           = 1
log_bin             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log.index
relay_log           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay_log_index     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
log_slave_updates   = 1
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I have clearly mentioned the server-d in `my.cnf` but also I am getting this error while stopping the slave.

```
 stop slave;
```

> ERROR 1794 (HY000): Slave is not configured or failed to initialize properly.
>   You must at least set --server-id to enable either a master or a slave.
>   Additional error messages can be found in the MySQL error log.

Anyone can please help me?

Comment: try changing `server_id` to `server-id`.

Comment: @IGGt, they are the same. The slave `server-id` need to be different from the master `server-id`. If that isn't have you done a `CHANGE MASTER TO...`? What does `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` show (formatted with `{}`)?

Comment: What's the server_id of the  Master?

Comment: tq everyone , it works ...really appreiciate ur help !!!